# Ошибка кодировки скрипта

Tags: javascript, jsp

Подключаю к JSP-шнику скрипт
`<script type="text/javascript" > <%@include file= "/WEB-INF/js/dataTables.searchBuilder.js"%> </script>`
но вместо русского текста он выводит "кракозябру" в виде множества DD

как это пофиксить?

Comment: Вангую, что кодировка основного и подключаемого скриптов - отличаются.

Comment: @Quazimorda Возможно, я скрипт подключал локально только потому что его надо было перевести на русский...

Comment: Я собственно о том, что если ваш сайт на кодировке cp1251, а подключаемый скрипт на utf-8 или наоборот, то нужно или этот единственный скрипт (попытаться) сохранить в вашей кодировке. Либо меняйте кодировку данных при входе в этот скрипт и обратно, при выводе данных из него, но это уже другая история. Лучше всего. когда весь ваш сайт уже в кодировке utf-8. Обычно сторонние скрипты или даже плагины поставляются в этой же кодировке.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Помогло это:

> Веб-сервер настроен так, что по умолчанию он отдает все страницы в
> кодировке windows-1251 (cp1251). Но это поведение можно изменить, для
> этого создайте в нужной папке файл ***.htaccess*** и поместите в него такую
> директиву:
>
> **AddDefaultCharset *имя_кодировки*** Здесь имя_кодировки — название той
> кодировки, которая используется в ваших файлах. Кроме windows-1251
> чаще всего используется кодировка UTF-8, в этом случае директива будет
> выглядеть так:
>
> ***AddDefaultCharset utf-8*** Если файл .htaccess в нужной папке уже
> существует, то просто добавьте эту строку в конец. Действие этой
> директивы распространяется и на все подпапки.